# execute ajax loaded javascript code

Tags: jquery, ajax, dom

I am loading piece of page that contains some javascript code as well, and `$.getScript()` approach wont work here as some of the javascript code is dynamically build through php.

```
<div id="fetch-me">
...
<script...>
var posts = <?php .... ?> 
...
</script>
</div>
```

As you might be familiar with this kind of issue, once I load this div with:

```
$("#load-me").load("... #fetch-me");
```

Javascript is not usable. I need to execute obviously. And I've tried few things but with no success. As an example this:

```
$("#load-me").load("... #fetch-me", function(){
 eval($("#load-me").find("script").text());
});
```

Any help appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`load` will return you the data it loaded in its callback.  Try to get the script(s) and append them to a `<script>` tag.

```
$("#load-me").load("... #fetch-me", function(data){
    $('<script>').html($(data).filter('script').html()).appendTo('head');
});
```

If there are multiple script tags in the loaded page, that may not work.  If that's the case, try this:

```
$("#load-me").load("... #fetch-me", function(data){
    $(data).filter('script').each(function(){
        $('<script>').html($(this).html()).appendTo('head');
    });
});
```

P.S. If this doesn't work, try changing `.filter` to `.find`.

Comment: I have only one script tag one that page, but unfortunately your first solution with neither filter nor find will append it to head.

Comment: Sorry man, my mistake. There were multiple script tags so I had to use 2nd solution it works like a treat. Many many thanks for your help!!

Answer (score 0):

Did you added quotes to string variables in javascript?

```
var posts = "<?php .... ?>"
```

Comment: This isn't needed if you did `var posts = <?php echo json_encode($x); ?>`.

Comment: This also isn't needed if the value was a number: `var posts = <?php echo $a/$b; ?>`.

Comment: I wrote, only if **string** value.

Comment: This is not an issue as this cod works perfect on page itself. Issue is to execute it after loaded with AJAX. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
$.get("page.php", function(data){
    //data is the information that page.php returns
    //Now instead of use this --> var posts = <?php .... ?>
    //do this:
    var post = data;
});
```

Comment: I assume there's more code in the `<script>` tag than just `var posts = <?php .... ?>`.